# convert ParseFile to image format

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloud

I´m a programmer student and I´ve never worked with parse before. I want to know if it is possible to retrieve a ParseFile and convert it to an image without using the method `getDataInBackground()` because I´m using an AsyncTask for retrieving all the data, images and other attributes of my class.

I tried using `getUrl()` but I got a `FileNotFoundException`.

This my code:

```
  URL url = new URL(parsefile.getUrl());
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                   
  urlConnection.connect();                  
  File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
  File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
  if(file.createNewFile())
  {
    file.createNewFile();
  }                 
  FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
  InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream(); // Here is throw the exception
```

The stack trace:

```
07-17 01:26:22.812: W/System.err(25516): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://files.parsetfss.com/f110277e-8601-4613-be7b-20c580591112/tfss-4d05240e-8e70-4920-aba2-4c62c776f509-1.jpg
07-17 01:26:22.812: W/System.err(25516):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
07-17 01:26:22.812: W/System.err(25516):    at foc.final_project.decanias.BackgroundTask.getBitmapFromURL(BackgroundTask.java:192)
07-17 01:26:22.812: W/System.err(25516):    at foc.final_project.decanias.BackgroundTask.retrieveBarSpecialties(BackgroundTask.java:116)
07-17 01:26:22.812: W/System.err(25516):    at foc.final_project.decanias.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:68)
07-17 01:26:22.820: W/System.err(25516):    at foc.final_project.decanias.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:1)
07-17 01:26:22.820: W/System.err(25516):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-17 01:26:22.820: W/System.err(25516):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-17 01:26:22.820: W/System.err(25516):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-17 01:26:22.820: W/System.err(25516):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-17 01:26:22.820: W/System.err(25516):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-17 01:26:22.820: W/System.err(25516):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-17 01:26:22.820: W/System.err(25516):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Thanks.

Comment: can u post ur Async class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ParseFile is a simple object that has a URL on it.  `getDataInBackground()` will download that asynchronously for you, and you can pass a callback with what to do after.

You are free to just grab the URL and download the file however you wish, too.

```
parseFile.getUrl();
```

Comment: Using `parseFile.getUrl();` I´m getting a FileNotFoundException

Comment: heh.. what are you trying to do with it?  log out that value, it is a *remote* url.

Comment: I have exactly this problem: https://www.parse.com/questions/getting-filenotfound-exception-when-trying-to-download-images-using-parsefile-geturl-method

Comment: From the comments there... "have to wait until the file save using saveinBackground() and then, save the main object"..  Add more code if this doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry I don´t understand, I want to retrieve a ParseFile that I saved in parse.com with the DataBrowser. So, why I have to call to the method saveinBackground()? Thanks :)

Comment: Please update your question with the entire code block you're using and any more information on the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .getData() method which is not async...